# SQL Server installation error can't find file `00ksrghd.rtf`

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I am trying to install SQL server 2016 
and this error always displays[image] to me as the attached image :

I got the mentioned path but I find that the file not there
how can i get this files

Comment: Are you running the installation as administrator?

Comment: yes, i run it as administration but the files not found

Comment: Also, you state you're installing SQL Server 2017; that image is clearly for SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Okay Sql 2016 sorry

Comment: Where are you installing ? is it local machine or server ?

Comment: Local machine @kuldipMCA

Comment: Delete the application and then try re-installing.  It looks like the original installation did not complete.  When installing make sure you install the full installation of SQL Server and not one of the partial installations.